# how to create search with sql Function

Tags: asp.net, select, sql-function

i want create a search page According to 3 field and show me records like them
**may functon**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Fun_SeachCustomers] 
(   
    @CName nvarchar(450) ,
    @mobile varchar(15),
    @State int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
SELECT 
      CEmail email
      ,CName name
      ,CorpName cropname
      ,Jens gender
      ,mobile mobile
      FROM TBLCustomers
WHERE CName LIKE @CName OR mobile LIKE @mobile OR State LIKE @State)
```

and i want show this fields in grid view and cells of table
**my Code**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT email, name, cropname, gender, mobile FROM dbo.Fun_SeachCustomers(@CName, @mobile, @State) AS Fun_SeachCustomers_1", conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CName", txtName.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", txtmobile.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", rbl.SelectedValue);

                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    ResGrid.DataSource = da;
                    ResGrid.DataBind();
                    ResGrid.Visible = true;
```

gird view is'nt show any things
and i dont know how to show records in cells of table

Comment: execute your SELECT query with values passed to check if anything is returned

Comment: yes it  worked correctly

Comment: but it can do better it show me  what  do not see